How to use the content of Icon Resource in code-behind mode situation in Avalonia framework
Background: we can usually use content of Icon Resource by AXAML in Avalonia framework such as this example
<PathIcon Data="{StaticResource mail_copy_regular}" ></PathIcon>

The mail_copy_regular is an object which is a StreamGeometry type and the icon resources provided by avalonia whose url is https://avaloniaui.github.io/icons.html.
Problem: I want to try to use content of icon resource in code-behind mode situation but I don't know how to do it.The reason for doing this is that I create the MenuItem object in code-behind mode and assign his property of icon. The icon is also an object and can be instantiated by the derived class PathIcon. By reading the official API documentation I found that PathIcon has a Data property which is of StreamGeometry type. I want to use the official icon resources provided by Avalonia to instantiate StreamGeometry.
I try to create the Data object in code-behind mode by setting StreamGeometry property of Data.
